# Noun for the act of withholding?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Merriam gives me "withholder", which is indeed a noun, but not for the act.

Sample use in a sentence:

"Even private schools have some contact with the outside world, preventing the *withholdment* (sic) of certain facts."

Naturally, an alternative could be to substitute the double negative with "encouraging the acquisition of certain facts", but this changes the meaning completely and is untrue, and is therefore not what I want to write.

Comment: One problem is that *withholding* is being used in an odd way here. Contact doesn't prevent anyone from withholding those facts. The withholding is done by the doer, not the receiver. Whereas the word *withheld* applies to the receiver, but only with respect to the one potential giver, not all givers. I would use *innocence* here. [...] ensuring the students do not remain innocent of certain facts.

Comment: Yes, I might have to rephrase it in the end. However, if there is a synonym to "the withholding of", I'm curious to find it. :) How about *redaction*? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redaction

Comment: Blockade, embargo?

Answer (score 8):

*Withholding* is the word you want. It acts as a noun in this context. See this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun) article.

Comment: That article doesn't even mention the word specifically. However, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/withholding) does indeed define it as a mass noun and adjective.

Comment: @JasonBassford - The link was meant to address the general idea of using verbs as nouns. The broader concept then can show that this specific case conforms.

Answer (score 1):

"Withholdment" is the noun you're looking for. This is found on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/withholdment), [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/withholdment), [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/withholdment), and many more.

The reason you may be unsure about this word is because it is a nominalization, or zombie noun. This is when you take a word that is not a noun (an adjective, adverb, or verb) and make it into a noun by adding a word ending like -ment, -tion, -zion, etc. These words can look weird because they seem to be "made up on the spot" but are actually correct.

A common piece of writing advice is to avoid zombie nouns, which make the writing feel overly formal and stiff, but because you only have one here, you're good to go.

Comment: The Oxford Living Dictionaries redirects _[withholdment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/withholdment)_ to _withholding_.  Dictionary.com says no results found for _[withholdment](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=withholdment&s=t)_ and asks if I meant withholding.  Merriam-Webster says "The word you've entered [isn't in the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/withholdment)."

Comment: @RogerSinasohn I see. Given that the dictionaries disagree, I think it's safe to say that both are fine to use. The only reason why I'd pause at using "preventing the withholding of certain facts" is because having two -ing words so close to each other like that (and functioning as two different parts of speech) makes me feel icky.

Comment: Google's ngrams viewer indicates that _withholdment_ is [virtually unheard of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=withholdment%2C+withholding&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithholdment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwithholding%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwithholding%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWithholding%3B%2Cc0) compared to _withholding_.  I'll note that the Wiktionary entry comes from an obsolete (100+ years old) version of Webster's Dictionary; the current M-W doesn't list it.

Comment: I don't see an issue with using _preventing the withholding of certain facts_; it flows easily and is clear.  Note that there are actually three _-ing_ words in a row there.

Comment: You've convinced me. I wouldn't take any issue with "withholdment" if I read it, but it's certainly outdated. I just personally don't like using too many -ing words in a row, however irrational my fear may be. I'd prefer to avoid using them in a row if I could, which would be my sole reason for using "withholdment" -- any other situation, I'd use "withholding".

Answer (score 1):

I have used 'withhold' as a substantive in a novel, as in, e.g.,'concerned about the consequences of his withhold'. It works for me. It may not be quote correct unquote, but prescriptivism is dead. Defensible objectively as an extension of 'hold' (n.) Also, the legal phrase "Withhold of Adjudication" is already current in some jurisdictions.